# How to disable `iptables` automatic reverse DNS lookup?

Tags: linux, iptables

It's a new "feature" added recently to `iptables` that whenever one lists `iptables -L` the IP addresses will be replaced by a domain name from reverse DNS. It's really annoying especially when I'm diagnosing a network issue and it just hangs because, well, there's no network. Is there a command line option to disable that, or even a patch?

Searching Google didn't help, since there is a related and vastly more popular topic(how to block DNS; redirect DNS; firewall rules for a DNS server etc.)

Answer (score 10):

This is mentioned in the `iptables(8)` [manual page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) [emphasis mine]:

> `-L`, `--list [chain]`
> List all rules in the selected chain. If no chain is selected, all chains are listed. […] Please note that **it is often used with the `-n` option, in order to avoid long reverse DNS lookups**.

> `-n`, `--numeric`
> Numeric output. IP addresses and port numbers will be printed in numeric format. By default, the program will try to display them as host names, network names, or services (whenever applicable).

This "new" feature, as well as the manual page note, have been present since at least 2000.

That said, for actually diagnosing iptables rules, you might find `-S` a bit more useful, as it shows the ruleset exactly as it was entered, instead of converting to a completely different layout.